# Does the "MIA" option in partykit::ctree() do anything, and--if so--how can we tell from the output?

Tags: r, ctree, partykit

Recently I've been trying to use the "partykit" R package and have found it difficult to understand how the `ctree()` function handles missing values. There is an option named `MIA` with somewhat cryptic documentation.

From the [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/partykit/html/ctree_control.html) in the function `ctree_control()`, we have the following description:

> MIA: a logical determining the treatment of NA as a category in split, see Twala et al. (2008).

The method is described pretty clearly in Section 2 of [the reference paper](https://oro.open.ac.uk/22531/1/decision_trees.pdf). Basically when determining splits that can be made for a variable X by considering a subset Y of its valus, the candidate splits are all of the following form:

1. ( X in Y or X missing ) vs. (X not in Y)
2. (X in Y) vs. (X not in Y, or X missing)
3. (X is missing) vs. (X is not missing)

However, when I run `ctree()` for data where the predictor has missing values, the tree output doesn't seem to reflect this at all. The split descriptions don't mention anything about missing values. To illustrate, I created example data where we predict an outcome variable `y` using a binary predictor, `x`, with values `"A"` and `"B"`. Some of the observations have missing values for `x`.

Below is a small reproducible example:

```r
library(partykit)

# Generate example data
# First 50 observations have high outcome values,
# last 50 observations have low outcome values
  y <- c(rep(11, times = 49), 6,
         rep(1,  times = 49), 6)
  x <- c(rep('A', times = 48), c('B', 'A'),
         rep('B', times = 48), c('A', 'B'))

  example_data <- data.frame(x = factor(x), y)

# Set some values missing
  example_data[['x']][c(51, 52)] <- NA
  
# Fit the tree
  ctree(
    formula = y ~ x,
    data = example_data,
    control = ctree_control(
      MIA = TRUE, majority = FALSE,
      maxsurrogate = 0
    )
  )
#> 
#> Model formula:
#> y ~ x
#> 
#> Fitted party:
#> [1] root
#> |   [2] x in B: 1.300 (n = 50, err = 120.5)
#> |   [3] x in A: 10.700 (n = 50, err = 120.5)
#> 
#> Number of inner nodes:    1
#> Number of terminal nodes: 2
```

From this output, I can't tell that the `MIA = TRUE` option did anything. It's not clear if missingness was taken into account when forming splits and--if so--which part of the split gets assigned the missing values.

Should I be doing something differently to get the missingness included in the splits and reported on in the `ctree()` output? Is this a bug? What's going on?